# Odoo v12 finding view ID

Tags: view, odoo

Im trying to find view ID to edit it. I know about developer options, but in this case it is not working...

Odoo v12 community version. Trying to edit a view adding a new customer, when adding a followers into task in project module.
Tried to find it in technical -> views but without success

More details - short video showing my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-oO7upPvto&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforehand: it is the view `base.view_partner_simple_form`.

How to find out? Yes, Odoo's debug mode is not helping that much here. But you can use it to find out what model is behind a field where you used "Create and Edit" context menu. In this case it's the model `res.partner`.

And from there you have to do a detective's work, or a bit like that. Just switch to the views list in technical and search for form views for model `res.partner` without a parent (base views not inheriting from other views). You will find 5-6 views and have to look into them one by one to find the right one.

For this case that is pretty simple, because there is only one view for `res.partner` model with so less fields in it.